# Grails JQuery UI Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, grails

I am trying to use the jQuery UI Progress bar in a Grails application for a file upload. I am using the g:uploadForm to submit the file and I am not sure how to go about getting a hold of the XMLHttpRequest object in order to get a hold of the progress on the transferring byte stream so I can feed the parameters to the jQuery UI progressbar to update itself. Here is what I am trying so far but no luck. I would immensely appreciate any guidance.

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: false,
            change: function() {
                $(".progress-label").text( $("#uploadErrors").progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
            },
            complete: function() {
                $(".progress-label").text( "Complete!" );
            }
        });
        $(".uploaderForm").submit();
        //var fileSize = $("#chseFile")[0].files[0].size;

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
            console.log(percent);
            $("#progressbar").progressbar( "value", percent * 100 );
        });
```

The controller's upload method is quite simple because it simply passes the work onto a Service:

```
def upload() {

    params.selectedBatch = selectedBatch

    // Diag
    println "*** Request info: " + request
    println "*** Session info: " + request.getSession()
    println "*** Servlet context: " + request.getSession().getServletContext()

    def f = request.getFile('file')

    if (f.empty) {
        println "File cannot be empty!"
    }

    else {
            // The case that we have an Excel file upload. This if statement might need to be
            // a switch statement in the future when we start accepting other upload formats like
            // CSV and/or XML.
            if (params.fileTypegrp.toInteger() == 1) {

                // We know its an Excel file, now we use a switch for the data type.    
                switch (params.dataTypegrp.toInteger()) {
                    case 1:
                        fileImportService.excelAccountFileUpload(params)
                        println "upload complete!"
                        break
.
.
.
```

Comment: I know this isn't really answering your question, but have you considered using one of the file upload plugins, such as [uploadr](http://grails.org/plugin/uploadr)?

Comment: I hadn't looked into that. I did see a few plugins but they seemed a little older so I wasn't sure if they still apply but I'll look into this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also paste your controller code here? I had done jquery progress bar before with GRAILS but without using g:uploadForm.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal I added the relevant controller code. Any advice highly appreciated. Thanks for your interest in my question.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman Sorry, I missed your edit and had added how I did it. Please take a look at my answer and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

UploadController.groovy

```
import grails.web.JSONBuilder

def uploadFile = {        
    if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
        for (filename in request.fileNames) {

            def uploadedMessage = StringUtils.EMPTY

            MultipartFile file = request.getFile(filename)

            JSONBuilder jSON = new JSONBuilder()
            JSON json = jSON.build {
                name = file.originalFilename
                size = file.size                    
            }

            results = json.toString()
       }
  }

  render results
}
```

Upload.gsp

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

<div id="progress" class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>

<script>
        jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({
          url: 'uploadFile',
          dataType: 'json',
          progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            jQuery('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
            );                
         }
        });

</script>
```

I have not tried this code completely but this should work, If you are getting any errors then please add a comment. I am assuming that you have all the necessary JS and CSS added.

FYI: I am using: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but I just can't figure out how to get the Javascript right. I have given up on having a progress bar after a week of struggle.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman I understand that it's pretty difficult to get all the things right when it comes to progress bars. I also faced lot of difficulties when I implemented it. However, I will see if I could write a blog post for it this weekend with a sample grails project.